# DOMParser in JavaScript doesn't give the XML elements

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

I have this XML:

```
<Walls>                        <!-- Added by edit -->
  <Wall Height="1.0">
     <Corner X="15" Y="9"/>
     <Corner X="23.5" Y="9"/>
     <Corner X="23.5" Y="8.5"/>
     <Corner X="15" Y="8.5"/>
  </Wall>
  <Wall Height="3.0">
     <Corner X="14" Y="5.5"/>
     <Corner X="24" Y="5.5"/>
     <Corner X="24" Y="5"/>
     <Corner X="14" Y="5"/>
  </Wall> 
</Walls>                       <!-- Added by edit -->
```

And I made a parser for this in JavaScript:

```
if (window.DOMParser){
     var parser = new DOMParser();
     var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingXMLSource, "application/xml");
     var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "application/xml");
}         
document.getElementById("Wall").innerHTML= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Wall")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
```

Now I want to have all the data from the XML, but in this way I cannot get it.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This XML isn't valid without a root node. Please update your question to show [runnable code that reproduces the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, sorry :( I'm really distracted! Thx

Comment: Two days passed and you still haven't fixed this issue? I did it for you, but it seems that you have abandoned this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect the [*nodeValue*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) to be for an empty element node? The *nodeValue* property is intended for For text, comment and CDATA nodes, perhaps you want to read the attribute values?

To read the attribute values, use *getAttribute*, e.g.

```js
var xml = '<Wall Height="1.0">' +
            '<Corner X="15" Y="9"/>' +
            '<Corner X="23.5" Y="9"/>' +
            '<Corner X="23.5" Y="8.5"/>' +
            '<Corner X="15" Y="8.5"/>' +
          '</Wall>';

if (window.DOMParser){
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
}

if (xmlDoc) {
  var nodes = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('Corner');
  var wall = document.querySelector('#Wall');
  var html = Array.from(nodes).map((node, i) =>
    `${node.tagName} ${i}: X=${node.getAttribute('X')}, Y=${node.getAttribute('Y')}`
  );
  wall.innerHTML = html.join('<br>');
}
```

```html
<div id="Wall"></div>
```

PS.  It helps greatly if you post your code as a runnable snippet.

Comment: thx. But this solution don't see the second wall. You can help me to see this?

Comment: @Walt057—as ggorlen said, the XML is not a valid document. Wrap it in another element, anything will do, e.g. `parser.parseFromString(\`<div>${xml}<\/div>\`, "application/xml")`.